# More specific rewrite rule is not applying

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The following are my rewrite rules,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^mypage$ index1.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index2.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I want to URI "/mypage" will rewrite to index1.php, or else rewrite to index2.php. But the URI "/mypage" always rewrite to index2.php and I dont understand why. How should I fix it?

Comment: Your code is in apache config or in htaccess file ? Did you try to reach `domain.com/mypage` or `domain.com/mypage/` (with trailing slash) ? Also, what's `mypage` in reality ?

Comment: my code is in htaccess file and I tried with trailing slash but not working, also mypage is not reality.

Comment: That's why it's not working. Your rule does not match a trailing slash. If you try `domain.com/mypage` (without slash) it should work. If you want to match trailing slash, replace your rule by `RewriteRule ^mypage/$ index1.php [L]`

Comment: I mean, not working with or without the slash

Comment: Well, what is the string `mypage` in your case ? Show me your real rule. Also, what apache version are you using ?

Comment: That is all I really rules, and my Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) and Apache/2.2.27 (Unix).

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. If you're using `mypage` as you said it should be internally rewritten to `index1.php`. Since you said everything was internally rewritten to `index2.php` i won't say it could be a mod-rewrite not enabled problem

Comment: Did you try my rules is working?  can tell me the results of your tested it?

Comment: I don't need to test it. Reading your code is enough and it should work considering what you said in your comments

Answer (score 0):

Yes your rules written such a way that `/mypage/?` is rewritten to `/index1.php` and then 2nd rewrite rule rewrites `/index1.php` to `/index2.php`. So in the end you get `/index2.php`.

To fix this behavior have your rules like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^mypage/?$ index1.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index2.php [L]
</IfModule>
```